# The list is created at the bottom of the widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need help! Faced a problem. I have a ListView created at the bottom of a parent widget. I just need to create a list at the top below the search bar so that everything is displayed according to the standard. I do not use any alignment widgets, but the list itself is equated to the bottom edge, it is not clear for what reason Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

```
Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 178),
                const BackStepWidget(text: 'Select Language'),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                SizedBox(
                  width: size.width,
                  child: Card(
                    color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 20),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                                    hintText: 'Search',
                                    hintStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: constants.Colors.white),
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.search,
                                      color: constants.Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice,
                                        color: constants.Colors.white),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                    )),
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(width: 14),
                              const Text('Cancel',
                                  style: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        // const SizedBox(height: 14),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 0),
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => Divider(
                                height: 1,
                                color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2))),
                            itemCount: language.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 9, bottom: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    language[index],
                                    style: constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    language[index],
                                    style:
                                        constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              // ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to wrap the `ListView` with a `MediaQuery.removePadding` widget
and add `removeTop: true` on it.

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
   context: context,
   removeTop: true,
   child: ListView(
       // your list view code.
   ),
),
```

Comment: Can you please show it with my code snippet? I just add but my code is underlined in red.

Comment: Everything worked out for me. Thank you very much for your help!